# Bot keeps executing random parts of loop

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to make a bot that sends a message whenever it detects page status changes, but after 3-5 seconds it randomly sends "server is online" even tho nothing changed in the page.

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time
import requests

def check(r):
    if "online" in r.text:
        return True
    else:
        return False

online = False

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = "#hidden"
GUILD = #hidden

client = discord.Client()

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})')
    channel = client.get_channel(#hidden)

    last_status = check(requests.get("#page"))
    while True:
        if check(requests.get("#page")) == last_status:
            continue
        else:
            if check(requests.get(#page")):
                await channel.send("server is online")
                last_status = check(requests.get("#page"))
            else:
                await channel.send("Server is offline")
                last_status = check(requests.get("#page"))


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have multiple runing instance of `on_ready`function.

Discord API often send (especially during this period of overload due to the pandemic) a instruction of reconnect.
When discord.py recieve this instruction, it reconnect and call on_ready again, without killing the other.

The solution is to use `asyncio.ensure_future` and `client.wait_until_ready` to be sure there is only one instance

code:

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time
import requests
import asyncio

def check(r):
    if "online" in r.text:
        return True
    else:
        return False

online = False

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = "#hidden"
GUILD = #hidden

client = discord.Client()

async def routine():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    channel = client.get_channel(#hidden)    
    last_status = check(requests.get("#page"))

    while True:
        if check(requests.get("#page")) == last_status:
            continue
        else:
            if check(requests.get(#page")):
                await channel.send("server is online")
                last_status = check(requests.get("#page"))
            else:
                await channel.send("Server is offline")
                last_status = check(requests.get("#page"))


@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})')

asyncio.ensure_future(routine())
client.run(TOKEN)
```